Are circles required on the edge of the grid?
The image below is a puzzle from the FlowFree app:

The image below is my solution to the above puzzle:

The rules stated in the app are:
Drag to connect matching colors with pipe, creating a flow.
Pair all colors, and cover the entire board with pipe to solve each puzzle.
But watch out, pipes will break if they cross or overlap!

For the example puzzle, there are two colored circles on the edge of the grid (a blue circle and a red circle on the bottom edge).
My question is:
Does there exist a grid (not necessarily square) with a set of colored pairs of circles in the grid such that there are no colored circles on the edge of the grid and there is a unique solution that satisfies the app’s rules?

The below answer is an optimization of Basss answer, it uses 1 color less:

 

The unique solution is as follows:

 

Edit (just for fun):
Additionally, if you want to use only 1 color that fill up every corner:

 


+1 Wow! Amazingly simple!

Your 2nd solution with the all green corner coloring reminds me of this Planar Langford sequence.

@WillOctagonGibson I was hoping to get them all in one line, but then the solution wasnt unique, unfortunately.

I posted a new related question here:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126848/are-circles-required-on-the-edge-of-the-grid-part-2

What about

 
     .   .   .   .   .

     .   A   B   A   .

     .   C   B   C   .

     .   .   .   .   .
 

with unique solution

 
     +---------------+
     |               |
     +---A   B   A---+
             |
     +---C   B   C---+
     |               |
     +---------------+
 


@Bass OP's "Pair all colors, and cover the entire board with pipe to solve each puzzle." sounds like that requirement to me. As for simpler I'd be curious to see how.

So it does. And the "much simpler" I had in mind had an alternate solution.

See first alinea in this answer: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47689. As far as I know, immediate turns are not allowed, so this is not a correct solution. There are multiple solutions to just 'connect the dots', only if you want to cover the entire board this is the only solution. I think @Bass second image is the best example there is, to cover the entire board with just connecting the dots.

@Lezzup One of the general rules mods keep reminding us of is puzzles should be self-contained, so unless it is something well established like chess or a sudoku the rules are what OP says. A link for explanation is not considered enough, much less requiring the solver to find by themselves an obscure post such as the one you are linking. As for this puzzle you seem to prefer different rules but they strike me as a tortured interpretation of what OP is actually writing and are certainly no grounds for calling my answer "incorrect".

I understand your point. Still, as the OP is specifically pointing to the game, you may assume that the official rules of that game apply. However, there is some uncertainty about this specific rule, I'll give you that. It was a bit harsh to call this answer incorrect, but I think the answer of Bass comes closer to a intended solution.

@Lezzup Fair enough.

@Lezzup The official rules of the FlowFree app may have changed over time.  On my version there is no mention of any restrictions on immediate turns.

@WillOctagonGibson I've been playing a long time and there has never been such a rule. Not every puzzle has a unique solution though, and switchbacks are usually a sign that you've found an unintended one.

The answer is

 
(See the answer at the source for spoilers.)

Here's a much less interesting way to see the same thing:

 


+1 That seems to work.  I wonder if there is a puzzle with a smaller grid or fewer pairs of circles.

I posted a new related question here:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126848/are-circles-required-on-the-edge-of-the-grid-part-2

Here's a relatively simple one here that should work:

 

Solution:

 

Simple, but I think it should satisfy the requirements.

Starting from the puzzle you provide in the question, you could

 extend the grid by one row below the bottom, and a column on each vertical edge

You could then

 start by travelling down from the blue and red that you have moved away from the edge, then away from centre, zig-zagging until you reach the other point of the same colour.

As shown in this (atrocious) diagram:

 

At its simplest, you could have

 just one colour, adjacent to each other, surrounded by a single square in each direction (forming a 4x3 grid), then starting at the top-left coloured point, travel left then clockwise around until you get back to the square below the start; where you then join to the other colour


 

There are infinite variants on such a solution, even with multiple colours

I would encourage you to post an image of your proposed solution.

@WillOctagonGibson done!

Your proposed layouts don't have unique solutions, though. For instance, in your first solution, cells B4 and B5 could be occupied by yellow line instead of blue line; and in your second, the solution could be mirrored around either axis.

ah, sorry, I missed the requirement for a "unique" solution

This solution is a slight simplification of the nice solution posted by Yout Ried.
Grid:

 

Solution:

 


The empty row in the center could be removed completely , and then it's (almost) the same as Bass answer.

@Lezzup I see what you mean.  I prefer grids where each colored circle is not immediately adjacent to its corresponding circle.

Seems like an interesting concept. I wonder if with that extra constraint, this answer is the most optimized :)

@Lezzup I don’t mind a colored circle to be diagonally adjacent to its corresponding circle (like your 1st solution). I just don’t want it to be horizontally or vertically adjacent.  I want the paths between colored circles to go through at least one intermediate square.
